# Is it possible to keep type-safty with kotlinx.serialization of a 3rd-party sealed class?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

There is an `Event` sealed interface with `UserConnected` and `EstimationSent` implementations.

```kotlin
data class User(
  val id: String,
  val displayName: String,
)

sealed interface Event {
  val id: String
}

data class UserConnected(
  override val id: String,
  val user: User,
) : Event


data class EstimationSent(
  override val id: String,
  val userId: String,
  val estimation: Int,
) : Event
```

These classes living in a 3rd-party module, thus cannot be annotated or modified.

Is it possible to make the `Event` sealed interface with its implementations serializable producing the following JSON?

UserConnected:

```json
{
  "eventId": "string",
  "data": {
    "userId": "string",
    "userDisplayName": "string"
  }
}
```

EstimationSent:

```json
{
  "eventId": "string",
  "data": {
    "userId": "string",
    "estimation": 42
  }
}
```

The goal would be to have a polymorphic serialization which possibly type-safe.

---

I have tried to implement a custom `KSerializer` and register it like this:

```kotlin
val format = Json {
  serializersModule = SerializersModule {
    polymorphic(Event::class) {
      subclass(UserConnected::class, UserConnectedSerializer)
      subclass(EstimationSent::class, EstimationSentSerializer)
    }
  }
}
```

However, this solution does not provide compile-time error if there is a missing `KSerializer` for an `Event` implementation.

Comment: I would not expect it to be possible to have a compile-time error there.